# java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: com.sun.tools.javac.util.ClientCodeException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, java-8, illegalstateexception

I am trying to adopt MVVM structure for that created some classes to get `remote` or `local` data using `repo` class with the help of `ViewModel` and I am also using `DI` to simplify the process

JDK version:

```
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

I am using java 8 like defined in: `build.gradle`

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 28

compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Exception at compile time:

```
> Task :module-app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: com.sun.tools.javac.util.ClientCodeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:442)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1005)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:138)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1047)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1004)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:441)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.util.ClientCodeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper$WrappedTaskListener.finished(ClientCodeWrapper.java:685)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.MultiTaskListener.finished(MultiTaskListener.java:111)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:987)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:223)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:187)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:95)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:398)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:65)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:389)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:118)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.TypeTreeVisitor.visitVariable(javacVisitors.kt:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.TypeTreeVisitor.visitVariable(javacVisitors.kt:50)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(JCTree.java:864)
    at com.sun.source.util.SimpleTreeVisitor.visit(SimpleTreeVisitor.java:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.TypeTreeVisitor.visitClass(javacVisitors.kt:75)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.TypeTreeVisitor.visitClass(javacVisitors.kt:50)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:720)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.MentionedTypesTaskListener.finished(javacVisitors.kt:39)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper$WrappedTaskListener.finished(ClientCodeWrapper.java:681)
    ... 45 more
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: com.sun.tools.javac.util.ClientCodeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
Execution failed for task ':module-app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

I am not able to find out what will be the error is? I have search a lot but still there is no relavent answer I have found. Is this Android studio error Or kotlin error or JDK error or eny code related error

Comment: Have you found the solution? Stuck with the same issue two days ago!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that it can be due to filenames duplication.
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/illegalstateexception-during-incremental-annotation-processing/14232

In my case it was a slightly different story (but similar in a term of duplication) - due to bad conflict resolution there were two similar companion objects in one class.

Spent two days, trying to identify the problem by commits comparisons